# configuring WCF services

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF Service (Service1) in localmachine and a Application consuming it.

There is a same WCF (Service2) in a another server(not local). Now if I want to delpoy my local application to server and some other person wants that application to consume service2 without any change in code. Is that possible?

Since my application only has Service1 reference.Is there any way to configure the service reference?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be an issue for a number of reasons:

1. The service names will probably be different meaning that it would be easy to point to the right service
2. It sounds like you have different applications on the same server (which is fine) which means that even if you had ServiceABC and ServiceABC the application names would be different meaning they could just point their application to App123.com/ServiceABC and you could point yours to App456.com/ServiceABC and there would be no issue

If I am understanding you correctly then there should be no reason to have to change any code that is currently pointing to the existing Service on the server